# Disable autorun completely in Windows 7 Home Premium

Tags: windows-7

How can I completely disable AutoRun for Windows 7 Home Premium?  For instance, when I open my  DVD drive in My Computer, I want to see the contents of the DVD instead of running autorun.inf.

I have disabled AutoPlay in the Control Panel, and selected "Take no action" for each media type.

Note that Microsoft has crippled gpedit.msc on Windows 7 Home versions, so that is not an option.  Bonus points if your solution works for all users.

Comment: `gpedit.msc` policies just cause registry settings to be applied at login, you could set those registry entries yourself.

Comment: @BenVoigt: that sounds promising, but I don't know what those registry settings are.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wikipedia has a comprehensive article on Autorun, including instructions on how to disable it for individual drives or types of drives.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AutoRun#NoDriveTypeAutoRun

Short instructions:

- open `regedit.exe`
- navigate to `HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer` (or `HKCU\...` if you want this to apply to the current user only)
- edit the entry `NoDriveTypeAutoRun` (or add it if it doesn't exist, type DWORD)
- a value of B5 (hexadecimal) should disable Autorun for removable and optical drives; a value of FF should disable it for all types of drives
- Reboot the PC

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick (after a reboot)!  But why in the world would Microsoft hide this setting in the registry?  What a terrible user experience.

Comment: Don't forget to include the same registry entry for `Hkey current user`.

Comment: @avirk That's not necessary, as the entry under HKLM will override any entry under HKCU. An entry under HKCU is only necessary if you want it to apply to just the current user, as I mentioned in my answer.

Comment: You can also disable it from the Local Group Policy editor: http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/disable-autorun-autoplay-in-windows-7/ or the Control Panel as William's answer indicates (by unchecking the "Use AutoPlay..." option or setting "Take no action" for specific types of CDs).

Comment: @Lèsemajesté Are you sure about that - the subject line is specifically about Windows 7 Home Premium, which does not have Gpedit.msc - as the comments in that article say

Answer (score 0):

If that is the action you want, then technically you do not actually want to disable.

What you want to do is go to the Autoplay settings and select `Open folder to view files using Windows Explorer` as the default option for each folder type.

I would personally recommend not doing this for Blank CD and a few options though.

[image]

Comment: No, that's not what I want either.  That pops up an explorer window every time I put a DVD in the drive.

Comment: @user133701: To be honest, your question said "I want to see the contents of the disc", which I also understood to mean "in an Explorer window".

Comment: @BenVoigt: I want to see the contents of the disc in an Explorer window when I open the disc in Explorer or the Run box.  I don't want anything to happen automatically when I insert the disc.

Comment: You mean by double click/single click(I'm assuming that you don't want right click to open the disc in explorer) on it should shows the content of of the disc instead of execute any exe operation am I right?